# Restructure array populated with duplicated keys and not lose data

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures, key

I'm trying to post form data to an API using PHP.
The API requires that the `screening_questions` have duplicate keys, like so:

[image]

I've gotten as far as having all fields correctly in the array to send except for the `screening questions`, which are multiple arrays inside the main array. I need to flatten or merge them so that the `screening_questions` aren't in nested arrays, but while attempting to do so it returns just the last `screening_questions` array since they all have the same key.

So this array:

```
Array
(
    [candidate[resume]] => CURLFile Object
        (
            [name] => /nas/content/live/powerhrg2/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/5-51403278f6166fe42c507d417f729fc5/2023/02/Power-HRG-Tech-Spec256.pdf
            [mime] => application/pdf
            [postname] => Power-HRG-Tech-Spec256.pdf
        )
    [candidate[first_name]] => John
    [candidate[last_name]] => Johnson
    [candidate[email]] => john.johnson@email.net
    [candidate[phone]] => 555-555-5555
    [job_posting_public_id] => 28038a67e70c7e235fa725bbf8b6e167d9e3efee1e43a304d73be8408c6f24a2
    [candidate[source_id]] => 7795
    [0] => Array
        (
            [screening_questions[][id]] => 1
            [screening_questions[][answer]] => false
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [screening_questions[][id]] => 6
            [screening_questions[][answer]] => true
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [screening_questions[][id]] => 11
            [screening_questions[][answer]] => true
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [screening_questions[][id]] => 16
            [screening_questions[][answer]] => true
        )
)
```

Should be this:

```
Array
(
    [candidate[resume]] => CURLFile Object
        (
            [name] => /nas/content/live/powerhrg2/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/5-51403278f6166fe42c507d417f729fc5/2023/02/Power-HRG-Tech-Spec256.pdf
            [mime] => application/pdf
            [postname] => Power-HRG-Tech-Spec256.pdf
        )
    [candidate[first_name]] => John
    [candidate[last_name]] => Johnson
    [candidate[email]] => john.johnson@email.net
    [candidate[phone]] => 555-555-5555
    [job_posting_public_id] => 28038a67e70c7e235fa725bbf8b6e167d9e3efee1e43a304d73be8408c6f24a2
    [candidate[source_id]] => 7795
    [screening_questions[][id]] => 1
    [screening_questions[][answer]] => false
    [screening_questions[][id]] => 6
    [screening_questions[][answer]] => true
    [screening_questions[][id]] => 11
    [screening_questions[][answer]] => true
    [screening_questions[][id]] => 16
    [screening_questions[][answer]] => true
)
```

I can't think of a way to merge or flatten those arrays?

I've only ever dealt with sending array data via POST - is there another way I can format this so that I can have these duplicated `screening_questions` with unique values?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code in it's entirety:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_5', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
    // get regular form field data
    $first_name = rgar( $entry, '1' );
    $last_name = rgar( $entry, '3' );
    $phone = rgar( $entry, '11' );
    $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
    $phone = preg_replace('/^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', '$1-$2-$3', $phone);
    $email = rgar( $entry, '6' );
    $resume = GFFormsModel::get_physical_file_path( rgar( $entry, '7' ) );
    $resume = new CURLFile($resume, mime_content_type($resume), basename($resume));
    $job = get_job(); // get current job ID & source ID
    $job_id = $job['id'];
    $source_id = $job['source_id'];
    // get screening questions id & answer data
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        if ($field['type'] === 'radio') {
            $field_values[] = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $field->get_value_export( $entry, $field->id )); // i.e. converts 'yes-1' to '1' 
            $field_names[]  = $field->get_value_export( $entry, $field->id, true ); // yes
        }
    }
    // remove empty data
    $field_values = array_slice(array_filter($field_values),0);
    $field_names = array_slice(array_filter($field_names),0);
    
    // combine screening id & answer
    $screening_questions = array_combine($field_values, $field_names);
    foreach ($screening_questions as $screening_question=>$sq) {
        // value must be true/false, not yes/no
        if ($sq == 'yes') {
            $sq = 'true';
        } else {
            $sq = 'false';
        }
        $question[] = array('screening_questions[][id]' => $screening_question, 'screening_questions[][answer]' => $sq);
    }
    // create an array of form data to send via the API
    $body = array(
        'candidate[resume]' => $resume,
        'candidate[first_name]' => $first_name,
        'candidate[last_name]' => $last_name,
        'candidate[email]' => $email,
        'candidate[phone]' => $phone,
        'job_posting_public_id' => $job_id,
        'candidate[source_id]' => $source_id,
    );
    foreach ($question as $q) {
        array_push($body,$q);
    }
    $post_url = 'https://pr29718.nitro-web.beta.hq.powerapp.cloud/recruiting/api/v2/candidates'; // TEST URL
    $pass = 'AMC0HNUK30RTFATWWKBJTW'; // TEST TOKEN
    $headers = array(
        'Host: pr29718.nitro-web.beta.hq.powerapp.cloud',
        'Authorization: '.$pass,
    );
    // Uncomment the below line to debug, if necessary
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: body => ' . print_r( $body, true ) );
    // Uncomment the below line to debug, if necessary
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: headers => ' . print_r( $headers, true ) );
    // Nitro API request via cURL
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://pr29718.nitro-web.beta.hq.powerapp.cloud/recruiting/api/v2/candidates',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    // Uncomment below line to debug, if necessary
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: response => ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
}
```

Comment: Rather than sanitizing the phone number then formatting it, do it in one step. `$phone = preg_replace('/^\D*1?\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})\D*$/', '$1-$2-$3', $phone);`  `\D` means a non-digit character.  `*` means "zero or more".  `array_slice()` from the first element onward is weird tool for what `array_values()` is built to do. https://3v4l.org/42a97  But to be honest, `array_combine()` doesn't need indexed arrays anyhow -- it doesn't care about the keys.

Comment: Just add your new associative elements directly to `$body` in your `foreach (`$screening_questions...` loop.  You don't need to overwrite `$sq` with that condition block -- when access the boolean `$sq`, just use the comparison's return value: `'screening_questions[][answer]' => $sq == 'yes'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter sending is wrongly defined. just put the subarray in the screening_questions[] array, what is the API response?

```
//next time pls define the variable before use.
$question = array();
foreach ($screening_questions as $screening_question=>$sq) {
  // value must be true/false, not yes/no
  $question[] = array(
    'id'     => $screening_question, 
    'answer' => $sq === 'true' ? 'true' : 'false'
  );
}

$body = array(
   'candidate[resume]' => $resume,
   'candidate[first_name]' => $first_name,
   'candidate[last_name]' => $last_name,
   'candidate[email]' => $email,
   'candidate[phone]' => $phone,
   'job_posting_public_id' => $job_id,
   'candidate[source_id]' => $source_id,
   'screening_questions' => $question,
);
```

Comment: `$sq === 'true' ? 'true' : 'false'` should be `$sq === 'yes'`.  And `$question[]` should be pushing directly into `$body` with `$body['screening_questions'][] = ...`  (with `$body` declared before the loop, of course.)